# Can a LayeredLayout be used on Tabs component Tab?

Tags: layout, tabs, codenameone, layered

Is it possible to implement a LayeredLayout over a specific Tab within a Tabs container? I would like to place a couple of buttons over an image which takes of much of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a Container in one of the Tabs and configure that Container to be LayeredLayout